# How to write a now.json file for a perfect deployment

Tags: json, deployment, vercel

I've developed a video chat application using the following tutorial https://www.sitepoint.com/webrtc-video-chat-application-simplewebrtc/ with the file structure:

```
simplewebrtc-messenger
├── public
│   ├── images
│   │   └── image.png
│   ├── index.html
│   └── js
│       └── app.js
├── README.md
├── now.json
└── server.js
```

I'm trying to use now.sh to deploy my application and i wrote the following now.json file for that

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "name": "VideoChat",
    "builds": [
        { "src": "/server.js", "use": "@now/node-server"},
        { "src": "/public/index.html", "use": "@now/static"},
        { "src": "/public/js/app.js", "use": "@now/node"},
        { "src": "/public/images/*.png", "use": "@now/static"}
    ]
}
```

But i end up with the folder view of the application after deployment.

I want the index.html file to be appeared as default page after deployment with all the functionality.

Comment: Try settings routes for your application https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/configuration#routes

Comment: For new comers; it's deprecated https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/5052

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As josh mentioned, you can use [routes](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/configuration#routes) to route specific paths to your output Lambda or static files.

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        { "src": "/server.js", "use": "@now/node"},
        { "src": "/public/index.html", "use": "@now/static"},
        { "src": "/public/js/app.js", "use": "@now/static"},
        { "src": "/public/images/*.png", "use": "@now/static"}
    ],
    "routes": [
        { "src": "/", "dest": "/public/index.html" },
        { "src": "/js/(.*)", "dest": "/public/js/$1" },
        { "src": "/images/(.*)", "dest": "/public/images/$1" },
        { "src": "/api", "dest": "/server.js" }
    ]
}
```

Alternatively, you could copy the entire `public` directory to the output using the static builder.

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        { "src": "/server.js", "use": "@now/node"},
        { "src": "/public/**", "use": "@now/static"}
    ],
    "routes": [
        { "src": "/", "dest": "/public/index.html" },
        { "src": "/(.+js|.+css|.+png|.+ico|robots.txt)", "dest": "/public/$1" },
        { "src": "/api", "dest": "/server.js" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Adding routes helped me set the index.html page as default, but that page is displayed without any styling and the button are not working, only their labels are displayed, and no video calling functionality is happening. All of this worked when i'm hosting it locally. You can check my online hosted page here https://hybridchat.gunachand.now.sh

Comment: @GunaChand There is no `css` deployed. Perhaps you forgot to include the css file in your `public` directory. I suggest using my second example. You can view the by appending `/_src` https://hybridchat-1obh7mbus.now.sh/_src

Comment: Also, I had a typo in my first `now.json` which I just fixed.